# Curve defined by the intersection between two scattered point surfaces, sampled differently

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I have two sets `1__scatter_xyz.dat` and `2__scatter_xyz.dat` of scattered points.

These points are defined by 3 coordinates: `x`, `y`, `z`

`1__scatter_xyz.dat` : https://paste.ubuntu.com/25069931/

`2__scatter_xyz.dat` : https://paste.ubuntu.com/25069938/

These two sets of scattered points intersect in a region:

```
gnuplot>  splot "1__scatter_xyz.dat" using 3:1:2 with points lt 1 title "1", "2__scatter_xyz.dat" using 3:1:2 with points lt 1 lc 2 title "2"

gnuplot> set xlabel 'x'
gnuplot> set ylabel 'y'
gnuplot> set zlabel 'z'
```

[image]

The crossing between the surface of `set 1` with the surface of `set 2` will define a line / curve, that plotted in a 2D `y`-`x`diagram, will give us the phase boundary between these two sets.

I would like to plot in a 2D `y`-`x`diagram this line / curve that arises from the crossing of both surfaces.

**The way I thought on how to attack this problem :**

We can define a new function, `w = z_{1} - z_{2}`.
The crossing between these two surfaces will be the points where `w = (z_{1} - z_{2}) = 0`.
I could then define two regions:

a) A region where `w = 0`

b) A region where `w \neq 0`

If I plot these two values of `w` in a 2D `y`-`x`diagram :

[image]

I could then define that this line / curve is the phase boundary between these two sets:

a) The region where `w = 0` is where both sets coexist together

b) The region where `w \neq 0` is where both sets do not coexist together

**Why I cannot progress with this solution:**

If we just remove the blank lines on the `.dat` files and sort `x`- wise:

```
sed '/^\s*$/d' 1__scatter_xyz.dat | grep -v "^#" | sort -k1 -n > 1__scatter_xyz_sort_x_wise.dat

sed '/^\s*$/d' 2__scatter_xyz.dat | grep -v "^#" | sort -k1 -n > 2__scatter_xyz_sort_x_wise.dat
```

If you look at both `x_wise.dat` files, there is overlapping data:
`set 1` goes from a `y` of -4.41 to 10.85, and `set 2` goes from 8.06 to 17.64. The array of `y` is different on both sets. However, the array of `x` is the same: from 10 to 2000 with a step of 20.1.

Thus, set 1 and set 2 have the same array of `x_{j}`: from 10 to 2000 in a step of 20.1.
However, both sets do not have the same array of `y`s: there is an array `y_{i}^{1}` for `set 1` and an array `y_{i}^{2}` for `set 2`.

In other words,

[image]

Thus, imagine that I find a point where both surfaces have the same value of `z`.
This point will be defined by `x_{j}`, `y_{i}^{1}` and `y_{i}^{2}` instead of two unique coordinates.

More efficient ideas are more than welcome.

## Using [`scipy`'s `griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata)  for this:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# Load data:
x_1, y_1, z_1 = = np.loadtxt(./1__scatter_xyz.dat, skiprows = 1).T
x_2, y_2, z_2 = = np.loadtxt(./2__scatter_xyz.dat, skiprows = 1).T

# According to the example posted in the above scipy's griddata link,
# variables "points" and "values" are defined, so we can similarly use:    
points_1 = (x_1, y_1)
points_2 = (x_2, y_2)
values_1 = (z_1)
values_2 = (z_2)
```

We would now have to define the grid. 
As explained deeply on the post, the array of `y` is sampled differently on both sets.

I we carefully study the data, there is a region of overlapping between both sets on the `y` space:

[image]

So, continuing with [this `scipy`'s `griddata` example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata), we can set:

```
T_initial = 10.0
T_end = 2000.0
number_of_Ts = 100

P_initial = 8.0622
P_end = 10.8535
number_of_Ps = 100

# And then define the mesh as:    
grid_T, grid_P = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(T_initial, T_end, number_of_Ts), np.linspace(P_initial, P_end, number_of_Ps))
```

**At this point I do not know how to continue, because we can actually just define two sets of grids ?**

```
grid_Gibbs_solid_1 = griddata(points_solid_1, values_solid_1, (grid_T, grid_P), method='cubic')    
grid_Gibbs_solid_2 = griddata(points_solid_2, values_solid_2, (grid_T, grid_P), method='cubic')
```

**Which would be the approach to follow ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let `f(x,y)` and `g(x,y)` denote the functions corresponding to your two surfaces. What you are looking for is to plot the *contour* corresponding to the equation `f(x,y) == g(x,y)`, or, equivalently `f(x,y) - g(x,y) == 0`.

Matplotlib offers the function `contour` for this purpose. As a simple example, consider the two surfaces given by the functions

```
import numpy as np    

def f(x, y):
    return np.exp(-(x**2 + y**2))

def g(x, y):
    return (3*x**2 + y**2)/16
```

The following snippet plots the function `f-g`, the (3D) contour corresponding to `f-g==0` as well as its (2D) projection on the `z`-plane

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X = np.linspace(-2, 2, 30)
Y = np.linspace(-2, 2, 30)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

Z = g(X,Y)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, f(X,Y)-g(X,Y), rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap = cm.viridis, antialiased=False, alpha = 0.5)
ax.contour(X, Y, f(X,Y) - g(X,Y), zdir='z', offset=-2, levels = [0])
ax.contour(X, Y, f(X,Y) - g(X,Y), levels = [0])
ax.set_zlim(zmin = -2)
```

[image]

In your case, you have data samples instead of functions. You may easily obtain (approximate) functions of the surfaces from your data by interpolation (see `scipy.interpolate`).

Comment: When using  scipy's griddata it is not clear which grid should I use (edited).